# Как получить ListBox значение

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

Работаю в EF. Необходимо взять элемент из списка, свериться с базой, что всё верно и добавить его в таблицу. Но вопрос состоит в том, как взять значение списка (ListBox), пробовал

```
var udkBook = db.UdkList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.NameUdk == UdkBookList.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

но не то. Точнее `SelectedItem != NameUdk`, хотя в начале именно значения `NameUdk` записываю. `NameUdk` - не первичный ключ, поэтому и использую `FirstOrDefault`..

Comment: А причём тут WPF? Значения нужно брать не из UI, а из VM, а лучше из модели.

Answer (score -1):

Добавление списка: ***var listUdk = db.UdkList.Select(p => new { p.IdUdk, p.NameUdk });                foreach (var p in listUdk) UdkBookList.Items.Add(p.NameUdk);***

Comment: Нет особой нужды давать два ответа, когда можно объединить в один. Пожалуйста, объедините в один пост. Также, если решение вас устраивает -- слева от поста есть галка "принять решение".

Answer (score -1):

Решение:  ***var selectedBook = (string) UdkBookList.SelectedItem;***